# Angular: add custom HTTP response headers to dev `ng serve`

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is it possible to add a custom HTTP response header to the development server that runs with `ng serve`? I'd like to add this custom header specially in the response of the main `html` file request, although it'd fine if it was added for every resource (`js` files, etc.).

I found these two recent Angular issues:

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15095
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15729

But it's still unclear to me if it's even possible to do it, and if it's possible how to accomplish it.

I have added a `proxy.config.js` file (referenced from `angular.json`, section `projects -> my-app -> architect -> serve -> options -> proxyConfig`) and tried several configs, like the following one, with no luck:

```js
module.exports = {
    "/": {
        'headers': {
            'X-Custom-Foo': 'bar'
        },
        onProxyRes: (proxyRes, req, res) => {
            proxyRes.headers['x-added'] = 'foobar';
        }
    },
    'headers': {
        'X-Custom-Foo': 'bar'
    },
    onProxyRes: (proxyRes, req, res) => {
        proxyRes.headers['x-added'] = 'foobar';
    }
};
```

Is it possible to do so without having to use a third-party server?

Comment: What do you mean if you can? a header can be anything you want, the important part is how you handle and use it on the server side.

Comment: I'm not sure why you expected setting the `headers` key to have that effect, following the docs from [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) via [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) to [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware) doesn't suggest that option would do anything.

Comment: @Bargros I'm not talking about HTTP request headers. I'm talking about HTTP *response* headers. I want the angular dev server to send a custom header to me.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not only setting `headers` (a desperate try), I'm also setting `onProxyRes` which should work. Any clue what is the right way to accomplish it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you done any debugging - does that function get called for the requests you're trying to add headers to? I don't think the proxy is used for the actual assets, the idea is to use it for e.g. backend API calls (and it isn't designed for production use either). I'd recommend giving more context on why you're trying to set these headers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe My use case is quite similar to the second angular-cli github issue I linked: I want to set certain security-related headers in my dev server to make it as similar as possible to the production server, the most important one being `Content-Security-Policy`. If it's not possible to do so it's a valid answer for me, but the references I found -specially the first one- leave the door opened, don't they? In spite of it, I wasn't able to achieve it (`onProxyRes` doesn't seem to get called) although I tried several different config combinations :/.

Comment: As they say, `ng serve` isn't intended for this - the first issue shows how to add headers *to proxied responses*, but as you've seen the Angular stuff isn't proxied (which makes sense, it's a fallback). I would test these issues at a later stage of the process; the dev server is just for local testing, use e.g. staging environments to test the app in a production-like environment, where you're actually serving the built assets too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to simulate the production environment setting the same response header values: you could use `bypass` in the proxy configuration instead of `onProxyRes`. You are not trying to redirect the calls to another server (`target` value) and handle the answer in `onProxyRes`, so avoid using it and try with `bypass`. It should work fine ;)

The proxy.conf.js would look something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  "/": {
    "secure": false,
    "bypass": (req, res, proxyOptions) => {
      res.setHeader('X-Header-Test', 'bacon');
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: OMG, it works! Thanks a lot, man. It'd have never occurred to me to do the trick with the `bypass` function. Awesome 

Comment: I used this but it seems to be working only for 1st call ,for other request calls it doesn't work.

Comment: @NamdeoKarande Try changing the `path` from `/` to `*`, it should be applied to any call instead of just the the first one.

Comment: @kayjtea it works for this purpose. Anyway, do you have any better solution or something you consider it will work? Thanks in advance

Comment: I spent quite a while on this with angular 8 -- I could not get it to work. But also, my proxy config is more complex,  with more routes.  I need ng-serve to insert the headers for static content but continue to pass some routes to my backend.  I gave up.

Comment: this not works - "bypass" and even "onProxyRes" are never triggered (hoverer js was processed (I put console log))

Comment: ```  }; ``` after ``` bypass ``` is invalid.

Comment: With the forceful requirement to add specific headers to server response in order to get `SharedArrayBuffer` working makes this solution even more useful in 2021 onwards. Saved me! Now developers need to, on their local machines, at localhost, 1) enable https 2) add custom header responses, all BEFORE they can even use ShareArrayBuffer in 2021, on their LOCAL machines. Woow!

Answer (score 11):

The solution through the proxy configuration didn't work for me (Angular 12). Turns out however that headers can be specified under the `options` for the `@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server` in your `angular.json` file, like so:

```json
{
    ...
    "serve": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
        "options": {
            "browserTarget": "project:build",
            "headers": {
                "Referrer-Policy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: i am using angular 7. For me too proxy is not working. I tried adding header in angular.json file at your specified location but it gives me error saying extra attributes are not allowed. Any suggestion?

Comment: the excat words of the error is 
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(headers).

Comment: Well my solution is for Angular 12 and beyond, so for Angular 7 you should probably use any of the older responses to this question.

Comment: well, nothing seemed working. I finally resorted to tomcat valve a webserver level change.

Comment: awesome works perfectly on Angular 12

Answer (score 2):

noga's answer is correct for what the `proxy.conf.js` needs to look like. In Angular versions 8+ (I'm guessing because of the stabilization of the new builder API and updates to webpack) more needs to be done.

This is all built on `webpack-dev-server` and `http-proxy-middleware`, and if you check out the info on webpack's site https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy it says:

> Note that requests to root won't be proxied by default. To enable root proxying, the devServer.index option should be specified as a falsy value

Unfortunately, `ng serve` does not expose this property directly and it is a sibling property of `proxy` which receives the output of `proxy.conf.js`. You can either make your own builder *or* you can dig deep into `node_modules > @angular-devkit > build-angular > src > dev-server > index.js` and insert `webpackDevServerConfig.index = '';` after `webpackDevServerConfig` is defined.

That works for me running Angular 9.

**UPDATE: Angular 11**

A commenter noted that this approach doesn't work for Angular 11. Now that I have bit the bullet and upgraded, I have a working solution.

The principle is still the same: the configuration of the dev server needs to have the `index` property set to the empty string.

After `config` is defined on line 87 of the same file as above, insert `config.devServer.index = ""`.

Comment: This did not work for me in Angular 11. `webpackDevServerConfig` does not even exist (its been renamed, and using the renamed version didn't work either).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I updated my answer to reflect how to do it in Angular 11

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 11, the above solutions do not work.

Since the context above is Development Server (which is my use case), what I ended up doing was simply start up Chrome by disabling CROS checking.

The benefits of this approach are: (i) avoid Angular or Node changes breaking you (ii) no changes needed to get local dev on different ports to work.

For example, on a Mac:

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security
```

Some more information below:

https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/

https://medium.com/@siddhartha.ng/disable-cross-origin-on-chrome-for-localhost-c644b131db19